How to run GitHub workflow on every commit of a push(more than 2 commits)
I have a problem. I want to run a GitHub action on every commit of a push.
I Have this integrate.yaml:
name: javascript-CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]
    
permissions: write-all

jobs:
  ci_to_main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: npm run test-once
      - name: Jest coverage report
        uses: ArtiomTr/jest-coverage-report-action@v2.2.6
        id: coverage
        with:
            output: report-markdown, comment
      - uses: marocchino/sticky-pull-request-comment@v2
        with:
            message: ${{ steps.coverage.outputs.report }}
      #####
      #- name: Run E2E Tests
      #  uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
      #  with:
      #    start: npm start
      #    wait-on: "http://localhost:1234"
      #####
      #- name: Build for deploy
      #  run: npm run build
      #- name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
      #  if: success()
      #  uses: crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages@v2
      #  with:
      #    target_branch: gh-pages
      #    build_dir: dist
      #  env:
      #    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

I want to run a GitHub action on every commit of a push.

Best practice is to only run CI on the tip of a push/PR as a PR may contain many small commits and not every commit is expected to pass tests. main is normally "protected" from pushes so everything has to go through the PR process.

This question is similar to: How to run GitHub workflow on every commit of a push. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
